# How Char(13) results in a new line in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the science behind the char(13) resulting in a new line in SQL server?
Always wondered how it works.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql. Do you guyz know what the F1 key do?

Comment: @DragandDrop Yes, it pops up an annoying window when I accidentally hit it. It should be disabled

Comment: Was always looking at char as a datatype and not a function that converts ASCII int to a character.Feeling enlightened.

Comment: This is not always related to ASCII (which is rarely used, anyway). It depends on the [collation for the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation). To be independent of the collation, you can use NCHAR(13). NCHAR and NVARCHAR are for [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long to comment, just to elaborate a little bit on the comments...

If you look at an ASCII table, you will see the decimal and character values for each. You can check / view these in SQL using the `ASCII` and `CHAR` functions.

```
select 
    ASCII_Decimal_Value = ascii('!')
    ,ASCII_Character = char(33)
```

The snippet above shows the decimal and character values for an exclamation point. Knowing this, you should understand why 13 and 10 is used for carriage return and new line, respectively, and how to use it. For example... if you run the code below in SSMS with the output as `Results to Text`, you can see the carriage return.

```
select 
    'This will be on the first line' + char(13) 
    + 'and this will be on the second'
```

Answer (score 3):

13 is [ASCII](https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php) the value of carriage return character.

Comment: 13 is for carriage return. 10 is new line

Comment: *Carriage return

Comment: Thank you everyone.